# discharging static

Tags: electrostatics

Quick question, if you have a buildup of static charge causing sheets of paper to stick together, can you have a grounding foil touching the paper to dissipate the charge to prevent pages from sticking together?

Comment: You could - but you'd need a foil between each pair of sheets, which might not be practical. It would be better to up the humidity in the air - that's a very effective way to reduce static buildup.

Answer (score 0):

There are three simple ways of discharging static. One is to work in a fairly high humidity environment. Another is to use a metal brush consisting of what are effectively needle points which are grounded and placed close to the static source. The final one is to use an air ionizer to neutralize/discharge the static.